# Javascript function with jquery css not functioning (No errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function that using jquery .css and simply passes the element, css property and the css value.

Here is the function:

```
function addCss(element, cssProperty, cssValue) {
   $(element).css({ cssProperty: cssValue }); 
}
```

And here's an example usage:

```
addCss('.container','flex-direction', 'row');
```

For some reason its doing nothing.

I'm I missing something or is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$(element).css({ [cssProperty]: cssValue });`

Comment: @max2020 to explain this, your code wasn't working because the it was always trying to set the CSS property `"cssProperty"`, rather than using the actual value of the variable `cssProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your object separately if you're in an environment that  supports ES6 computed property names.

```
function addCss(element, cssProperty, cssValue) {
   var rule = {};
   rule[cssProperty] = cssValue;
   $(element).css(rule); 
}
```